# How to pass jenkins credential parameter as Authentication header in powershell http post request

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am trying to access the below POST call using powershell
post call `http://pathandport//computer/agentname/api/json?pretty=true`

From jenkins, I am calling a powershell file which accesses the rest api with user name and password passed as a plain text from jenkins

```
$pair= "$($username):$($password)"
$encode= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$Auth= "Basic $encode"
$Headers = @{ Authorization = $Auth }
$url = 'http://<path>:<port>//computer/agentname/api/json?pretty=true'
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $Headers
```

The scenario works fine when we pass user name and password as a plain text.

Recently came to know about jenkins credentials param(User name with password) where it gets the user name and password, encodes as a token with its inbuild logic and generates a value similar to this "1234-abcd-5678-efgh".

My issue now is, i am not able to pass this token as a Auth value in powershell request with above implementation.

Help me how to handle this

Comment: Welcome to SO! Interesting problem indeed.

Answer (score 2):

When using credentials in Jenkins and [the Username and Password credential you are referencing](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#usernames-and-passwords), Jenkins exposes the username:password pair as an environment variable but also exposes the username and password individually.

```
environment {
  BITBUCKET_COMMON_CREDS = credentials('jenkins-bitbucket-common-creds')
}
```

this actually sets the following three environment variables:

> BITBUCKET_COMMON_CREDS - contains a username and a password separated
> by a colon in the format username:password.
>
> BITBUCKET_COMMON_CREDS_USR - an additional variable containing the
> username component only.
>
> BITBUCKET_COMMON_CREDS_PSW - an additional variable containing the
> password component only.

so your powershell should look like this:

```
$pair= "$MY_CREDENTIALS"
# or you could also do this
# $pair= "$MY_CREDENTIALS_USR:$MY_CREDENTIALS_PSW"

$encode= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$Auth= "Basic $encode"
$Headers = @{ Authorization = $Auth }
$url = 'http://<path>:<port>//computer/agentname/api/json?pretty=true'
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $Headers
```